# Use join inside Script.RenderFormat

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, join, razor

I want to use ASP.net MVC bundling together with this script

```
[
'1.js',
'2.js'
].forEach(function (src) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

But I can't seem to understand how I could use `Script.RenderFormat` to achieve the above.

Currently I use `RenderFormat` like this:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/client/js")
```

Comment: Because data is the JSON. But @Scripts render with C# data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. Go to App_Start/BundleConfig.cs:

The code:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr")
            .Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*")
            .Include("pathToFile/*.js")); // '*' can be 1, 2, a, b, abc,...
```

Maybe, you should learn Bundle in asp.net mvc.

Refer here: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/c72b040113-Asp.net-MVC-4-performance-optimization-with-bundling-and-minification.html

Hope this help.

Comment: But this requires me to write all file paths in JavaScript. What I want to do, is leverage mvc bundling where all my files are referenced.